# How do I add a generic "controller/action" route with Akhet's add_handler?

Tags: routes, pylons, pyramid, akhet

I'm moving from Pylons to Pyramid/Akhet, and I'm confused by the setup.

Is there any way to add a generic "controller/action" route with Akhet's `add_handler` method?
(or even with the `add_route` method in base Pyramid?)

The way I'm understanding it, it seems like I need to do a `new add_handler()` call for every new controller I add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for a `{controller}` or `{handler}` wildcard in pyramid_handlers. You will need to call `add_handler` at least once per handler. This is one of the bw-incompat changes users have to go through when moving from Pylons.

Comment: Well that sucks.  Thanks for the confirmation.